# A plugin that automatically slides in a big image

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I saw a plugin possibly a slideshow plugin that slides in y-axis in a big image.

I dont know how to put it right but lets say visible image is 600px to 300px but the real image is 600px to 600px that plugin was scrolling the visible part so that all the content was seen in an interval.

I cant remember its name so ,i really need to find its name or something of an equivalent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'd need a plugin for that. With a bit of work, you should be able to do something like that with [jQuery's animate() method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: I am so so short on time but i will try to do something like that till i find anything.

Comment: Done as you said, it was way easier than i think, thanks for the answer.